# Prevent Notebook from resuming from Standby while on Battery

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery, sleep, wake-up

A recurring problem I see with notebooks is having them resume from standby or hibernation while on battery. 
This can be caused by a wide range of possible reasons, ranging from network activity over planned tasks to unplugging a USB mouse, making identification and fixing of the issue unreliable ("Did I catch all? Will a new one show up?") and time-consuming. All related topics I found were correspondingly based on the same process of "identifying the culprit and turning it off".

My target is to disable permanently all possible sources of wake-ups while on battery, since being on battery indicates the notebook likely being in a bag, and thus wake-ups holding the risk of overheating the hardware (potential of hardware damage or, depending on quality, even a fire hazard?).

Is there some simple solution to solve this once and for all, be it a comprehensive registry hack, startup script or a third party utility?

I am primarily looking for a solution for Wiindows 8.1, but a utility with support for previous and expected support for future OS versions would be preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options:

- turn the notebook off
- hibernate it

sure, both take longer to get back to work than doing a standby, but then a modern laptop has an SSD and is fast, a hibernate won't cost you that much time ...

Comment: Is hibernate a guarantee against wake-ups though? Also, when frequently suspending the device during the day, hibernate may cause undesireable write-loads (potentially reducing SSD lifetime). It sounds like a viable option, though disabling wake-on-battery for standby would still be better.

Comment: @kdb: let's assume 10 hibernations/day over 10 years: that's 36'500 write ops .. well short of what the SSD should be able to handle .. and the OS should not be able to wake from hibernation (not 100% sure here, though)

Comment: A quick search showed that there CAN be at least maintenance tasks waking devices from hibernation. I am trying it for now though, but I'm still hoping that there is a more definite answer.

Comment: I found http://productivityscientific.com/BackToSleep/ via http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/laptop-wakes-itself-while-inside-carrying-case/cb9830e7-74f1-4ca7-96e0-4f78ffaa4364 . While it seems somewhat expensive for what it does, and I still think Windows should avoid potential fire hazards by default, it might be the only viable solution.